# How could I prove or disprove that the sum of two positive odd integers is never prime?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, prime-numbers

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's always even

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  What about $1+1$?

Comment: the sum of two odd numbers is even. ... So it can only be true if they add to $2$ which is the only even prime.  Which is possible if they are both $1$.  If you add a condition such as two different positive odd integers, or two odd primes, or something you can get such a statement.

Answer (score 2):

You could disprove the statement with a counterexample:  $1+1=2,$ which is prime.